# How to convert "datetime-local" to Unix time and compare it with the current date/time in vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

In my application, the user should be able to submit a date and time, then I need to compare the date/time with the current date (I need to check if the date/time submitted from the user has passed, or for example, if it will pass within 24H). In my html file, I have:

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="dateInput" />
```

And in my Javascript file, I am calling it as such:

```
var dateValue = document.getElementById("dateInput").value;
```

I'd like to compare dateValue with the current date/time (for example by using dateValue > Date.now() ), however, they are in different formats. For example, the log from console

```
console.log('Comparing ', dateValue, " with " , Date.now() )
```

Returns:

```
Comparing  2019-06-12T19:30  with  1552409011189
```

**Without using external libraries, how can I convert dateValue in Unix time so that I can compare it to Date.now() ?**

Comment: @Alberto want to flag this as a duplicate?

Comment: @StevenStark Yes, seems very similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const date = +new Date(dateInput.value)

console.log(date, Date.now())
```